# Having an NSSet as part of an NSManagedObject in Core Data

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsset

I have a class which as its properties has a number of NSSet values. The content of these sets is not stored in Core Data, but comes from another source. They are basically ID strings which are unique. No point in filling up Core Data with them as separate entities.

However, as far as I can see it's not possible to store an NSSet as an attribute of an NSManagedObject. I guess I would need to serialise it into binary data by hand, whenever the object gets stored, and deserialise it when it gets retrieved from the persistent store? The same would also apply to storing other collection classes.

Has anybody else ever come across this issue and is able to give some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the attribute type to 'transformable' and then directly store the set into the attribute. Be sure that all of the contents of the set conform to `< NSCoding >`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! The UUID strings are already NSCoding compliant.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, in the Project Navigator open up the project_name.xcdatamodeld source for the model editor and select the entity in question. Choose Editor in the Xcode menu bar and there is a Create NSManagedObject subclass... item. Make the subclass and use it for extra non-Core Data properties. The subclass becomes part of the model in place of the entity. It retains all of the entity's behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not my problem: the NSManagedObject subclass I'm using (sorry, wasn't very clear on that in my question) has an NSSet as a property which I want to be stored in Core Data, and it's the storing of that collection that gives me the headache.